# How can I enable decimals in my chart in Swift?

Tags: swift, charts

I am using Charts to create my own charts but I am struggling to see the values of my table with decimals instead of just integers.

My chart init is like below, but I cannot find the way to format the points to show the decimal parts since they are doubles. I have tried to set `targetChartView.xAxis.decimals` and `targetChartView.leftAxis.decimals` without result.

How can I enable the decimal notation?

```
init(withGraphView aGraphView: LineChartView, noDataText aNoDataTextString: String, minValue aMinValue: Double, maxValue aMaxValue: Double, numberOfDataSets aDataSetCount: Int, dataSetNames aDataSetNameList: [String], dataSetColors aColorSet: [UIColor], andMaxVisibleEntries maxEntries: Int = 10) {
    originalMaxValue     = aMaxValue
    originalMinValue     = aMinValue
    dateFormatter        = DateFormatter()
    targetChartView      = aGraphView
    lineChartData        = LineChartData()
    maximumVisiblePoints = maxEntries
    timestamps           = [Date]()

    for i in 0..<aDataSetCount {
        let firstEntry = ChartDataEntry(x: 0, y: 0)
        var entries    = [ChartDataEntry]()
        entries.append(firstEntry)
        let aDataSet = LineChartDataSet(values: entries, label: aDataSetNameList[i])
        aDataSet.setColor(aColorSet[i])
        aDataSet.lineWidth = 3
        aDataSet.lineCapType = .round
        aDataSet.drawCircleHoleEnabled = false
        aDataSet.circleRadius = 2
        aDataSet.axisDependency = .left
        aDataSet.highlightEnabled = true

        lineChartData.addDataSet(aDataSet)
    }

    targetChartView.data = lineChartData
    targetChartView.noDataText = aNoDataTextString
    targetChartView.chartDescription?.text = ""
    targetChartView.rightAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false
    targetChartView.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
    targetChartView.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
    targetChartView.leftAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
    targetChartView.dragEnabled = true
    targetChartView.xAxis.granularityEnabled = true
    targetChartView.xAxis.granularity = 1
    targetChartView.xAxis.decimals = 0
    targetChartView.leftAxis.granularityEnabled = true
    targetChartView.leftAxis.granularity = 1
    targetChartView.leftAxis.decimals = 0
    targetChartView.xAxis.axisMinimum = Double(0)
    targetChartView.xAxis.axisMaximum = Double(maximumVisiblePoints)
    targetChartView.leftAxis.axisMinimum = aMinValue
    targetChartView.leftAxis.axisMaximum = aMaxValue
    targetChartView.setScaleEnabled(false)
    super.init()
    targetChartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = self
    targetChartView.delegate = self

    // This gesture recognizer will track begin and end of touch/swipe.
    // When user presses the graph we don't want it to be moving when new data is received even when the most recent value is visible.
    let clickRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didLongPress))
    clickRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 0
    clickRecognizer.delegate = self
    targetChartView.addGestureRecognizer(clickRecognizer)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned to @Sulthan, the issue was not in the chart itself but how the data set (`aDataSet`) had to be formatted, so adding the snippet below enabled three decimals on my data in the graph

```
init(withGraphView aGraphView: LineChartView, noDataText aNoDataTextString: String, minValue aMinValue: Double, maxValue aMaxValue: Double, numberOfDataSets aDataSetCount: Int, dataSetNames aDataSetNameList: [String], dataSetColors aColorSet: [UIColor], andMaxVisibleEntries maxEntries: Int = 10) {

        originalMaxValue     = aMaxValue
        originalMinValue     = aMinValue
        dateFormatter        = DateFormatter()
        targetChartView      = aGraphView
        lineChartData        = LineChartData()
        maximumVisiblePoints = maxEntries
        timestamps           = [Date]()
        //Setting 3 decimals for the number that are going to be displayed
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()//ADD THIS
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal//ADD THIS
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 3//ADD THIS
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 3//ADD THIS

        for i in 0..<aDataSetCount {
            let firstEntry = ChartDataEntry(x: 0, y: 0)
            var entries    = [ChartDataEntry]()
            entries.append(firstEntry)
            let aDataSet = LineChartDataSet(values: entries, label: aDataSetNameList[i])
            aDataSet.setColor(aColorSet[i])
            aDataSet.lineWidth = 3
            aDataSet.lineCapType = .round
            aDataSet.drawCircleHoleEnabled = false
            aDataSet.circleRadius = 2
            aDataSet.axisDependency = .left
            aDataSet.highlightEnabled = true

            lineChartData.addDataSet(aDataSet)
            //Use formater that allows showing decimals
            lineChartData.setValueFormatter(DefaultValueFormatter(formatter: formatter))//ADD THIS
        }
    ...}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `decimals` property is used only if you are using the default formatter. However, I see that you are also setting

```
targetChartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = self
```

That means your class is implementing `IAxisValueFormatter` and its `stringForValue(:axis:)` method. The value in `decimals` (which should be nonzero) is then ignored because you have a custom formatter.

You can either remove the assignment and then your decimals should be displayed or, you will have to format your decimals correctly in `stringForValue(:axis:)`.

You have not added this part of your implementation but the problem is probably there.

I see there is also some magic in the `AxisRenderer` that will probably remove decimals if the interval between values is bigger than 1. Therefore using a custom formatter for both axes is probably the best solution.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I have removed the line `targetChartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = self` and set `decimals = 3` but still I get no decimals. I start to wonder, maybe it the data set the one that has to be set to display decimals and not the graph?

Comment: @ndarkness As I said, the safest solution is to use your own formatter but you have to implement it correctly.

Comment: thanks I have already found the solution, I had to format the data not the chart

Comment: @ndarkness Yes, you have done exactly what I have told you to do.